# Python Selenium JavaScript Horizontal Scroll

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I'm not very good at using pyhton/selenium on a website using javascript.

I have a website that will only read the source for what is visible. So I am trying to scroll to the right a handful of pixels at a time to get the whole table eventually.

The scroll element looks like this:

```html
<div class="ag-body-horizontal-scroll" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 17px; max-height: 17px; min-height: 17px;">
        <div class="ag-horizontal-left-spacer ag-scroller-corner" ref="eLeftSpacer" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"></div>
        <div class="ag-body-horizontal-scroll-viewport" ref="eViewport" style="height: 17px; max-height: 17px; min-height: 17px;">
        <div class="ag-body-horizontal-scroll-container" ref="eContainer" style="height: 17px; max-height: 17px; min-height: 17px; width: 7400px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-horizontal-right-spacer ag-scroller-corner" ref="eRightSpacer" style="width: 17px; max-width: 17px; min-width: 17px;"></div>
    </div>
```

Would love some help on getting this to work.

Comment: If you scroll the element to the right a bit and then do this in console: `$$('*').filter(el => el.scrollLeft)` that will tell you which element you need to scroll

Comment: perfect, thanks!